# Listening/Handling JPanel events

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jpanel, event-listener

Good evening ladies and gentlemen,

I have a problem with Java Swing that I cannot solve, maybe you can help me. Here it is:

- I have one JFrame which uses BorderLayout, and many JPanels.
- Every time I need to put up a new screen (i.e. from the Main Menu, when Search button is clicked, go to the Search Menu), I simply remove the component (JPanel) which is located in the center, and put the new screen (new JPanel) in the center instead.
- This way, I don't call all my header and footer objects every time I want to put up a new screen.

Everything works fine with this system except this little problem: I want to trigger some methods everytime I put up a new JPanel or change back to an existing JPanel (generally speaking, everytime a JPanel appears).

In order to do that, I tried to implement ComponentListener's componentShown(ComponentEvent e) method, and added a ComponentListener to a JPanel which I put up in the center of my JFrame, and it did NOT work. After this, I did some research and found out that this componentShown (@ComponentListener) method only works when the visibilty of the JPanel is changed (from invisible to visible or the opposite). Unfortunately, I'm not changing the visibility of a JPanel, just replacing it with another one: removing the current one, and adding the new one. Below code illustrates how I replace the JPanels.

```
// Get the JPanel located in the center of our JFrame
JPanel currentView = (JPanel) myFrame.getContentPane().getComponent( 2 );

if ( currentView != null )
{
   // Remove it from the JPanel         
   myFrame.getContentPane().remove( currentView );
}

// Add the new JPanel    
myFrame.getContentPane().add( otherView, BorderLayout.CENTER );

// Pack the JFrame and show it
myFrame.pack();
```

So here is what I have. I would really appreciate it if you could help me out.

Comment: What you could do instead of adding/removing `JPanel`s yourself is to use one `JPanel` in the `CENTER` of your `contentPane` with a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html). [How to use `CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: @Jeffrey, thank you for your fast-response. What you are saying is nice and reasonable, but what I'm dealing is a group-work. We have a pattern that we are following for now, and before suggesting to change our pattern (BorderLayout --> CardLayout), I want to -at least- try to come up with a solution with the current pattern.

Comment: Just because you're using BorderLayout doesn't mean that you can't also use CardLayout as they're not mutually exclusive. The BorderLayout.CENTER panel could be the card-holder, the JPanel that uses CardLayout.

Comment: I do not think I understand your question. You have the code which switches from one panel to another, and you are asking how to do something extra after switching panels ... why not simply add the code after you call the `add` method instead of trying to use listeners ?

Comment: the intuitve "visibility" notification happens via an AncestorListener: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/AncestorListener.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this issue corresponding with [HierarchyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/HierarchyListener.html), for comparing

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ContainerListener extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ContainerListener() {
        super("Test");
        setContentPane(new TestPanel());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] parameters) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ContainerListener containerListener = new ContainerListener();
            }
        });
    }

    private class TestPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        TestPanel() {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add label") {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                private int n = 0;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    TestPanel.this.add(new JLabel("Label " + ++n));
                    validate();
                }
            }));
            addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener() {

                @Override
                public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Components Change: " + e.getChanged());
                    if ((e.getChangeFlags() & HierarchyEvent.DISPLAYABILITY_CHANGED) != 0) {
                        if (e.getComponent().isDisplayable()) {
                            System.out.println("Components: " + e.getChanged());
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Components: " + e.getChanged());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            addContainerListener(new ContainerAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("componentAdded : " + event.getChild() + "containerName" + " was added");
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. When I use HierarchyListener instead of ContainerListener, it worked!!

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend listening to the advice given by @Jeffrey, but if you do proceed with this design, then perhaps implementing the [`ContainerListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ContainerListener.html) interface may prove useful.

When in doubt, consult the API.

Comment: I have just tried your solution and implemented the ContainerListener. It perfectly worked with newly created JPanels. Unfortuntaly, it's not working when returning to an existing JPanel. Whether return to an existing JPanel or creating a new one and putting up its view, I always use the same way above to delete and add a view to my frame. I didn't understand why it isn't working when putting an existing panel to a frame... :S

Comment: You'll need a `WindowListener`, `WindowFocusListener` or `WindowStateListener` for that.